# Firebase AUTH - exceeding limitations functional result

Tags: firebase, authentication

I have a question regarding the firebase AUTH API. According to firebase you can perform 1000 requests per second / per project. I would like to know what happens if you exceed that limit and have, let's say 2000 users logging in at the same time / second. Will the 1000+ users receive an error? Or will they be queued to the next available slot? The documentation does not say that.

We are on the blaze plan btw.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I am pretty sure that they will stop incoming requests or move you to the blaze plan.

Comment: We are on the blaze plan. Do you mean that should not make a difference?

Comment: Hmmmm. Then I will guess that it will stop accepting requests for that second.